# Lottery is not working, specific details missing

Tags: javascript, random

I tried to make a small lottery picking 6 random numbers out of 49 which are all different. This is what I came up with but something isn't working. Can you tell me what is wrong and correct the code?

```js
function getNumbers(){
    var numbers = [];
    var randomnumber;
  
    while(numbers.length < 6){
            randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*49)
            if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
            numbers[numbers.length] = randomnumber;
    }

    numbers.sort(sortNumber);
  
    document.getElementById("Ausgabe").innerHTML = numbers;
}

function sortNumber(a,b) {
     return a - b;
}
```

Comment: `arr.indexOf` should probably be `numbers.indexOf` Are there any errors in the console window?

Comment: _"but something isn`t working"_ That's a really detailed problem description

Comment: Well that was it. Thanks for helping I totaly overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1)` should be replaced by 
`numbers.indexOf(randomnumber)`

so **arr** `->` **numbers**

```js
function getNumbers(){
    var numbers = [];
    var randomnumber;

    while(numbers.length < 6){
            randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*49)
            if(numbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
            numbers[numbers.length] = randomnumber;
    }

    numbers.sort(sortNumber);

    document.getElementById("Ausgabe").innerHTML = numbers;
}



function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

getNumbers();
```

```html
<div id="Ausgabe" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works to me. You should use your `numbers` array instead of `arr`.

Html:

```
<p id="Ausgabe"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getNumbers(){
        var numbers = [];
        var randomnumber;


    while(numbers.length < 6){
            randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*49)
            if(numbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
            numbers[numbers.length] = randomnumber;
    }

    numbers.sort(sortNumber);

    document.getElementById("Ausgabe").innerHTML = numbers;
}



function sortNumber(a,b) {
        return a - b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one major problem which the others have missed. You forgot to call the function. lol.

Second error is that you wrote arr instead of numbers in the if statement.

Comment: Jah it´s the second one